# Count occurrences of a String in a String[] by a Map<String, AtomicInteger>

Tags: java, dictionary, linkedhashmap

The following method is supposed to count the occurrences of each item in the given set:

```
void groupBy(String[] stuff)  {
LinkedHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> A = new LinkedHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();

final AtomicInteger one = new AtomicInteger(1);
AtomicInteger count;

for (String key:stuff)  {
    count = A.get(key);
    if (count==null) A.put(key, one);
        else System.out.println("Previous value  :"+A.put(key, new AtomicInteger(count.incrementAndGet())));
}

  Set set = A.entrySet();
  Iterator ii = set.iterator();

  while(ii.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)ii.next();
     System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
     System.out.println(me.getValue());
  }
}
```

So, if I run it on param

```
String a[] = {"AAA", "A", "AA", "B", "A", "AAA"};
```

i'm supposed to get

```
Previous value :1
Previous value :1
AAA: 2
A: 2
AA: 1
B: 1
```

But, what i'm getting is

```
Previous value :2
Previous value :3
AAA: 3
A: 2
AA: 3
B: 3
```

the values in the hash are updated beyond what i intend to do and i havent an idea how.

help appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason you used `AtomicInteger` ? You have made simple program a real complicated issue.

Comment: @Prateek - Yes. to do the increment compact.

Comment: meaning of `increment compact`?

Comment: The only reason to use `AtomicInteger` would be if this was in a multi-threaded program.  Otherwise it is totally unneeded and overly complicated. Is that your use-case?  And if it is, you are using `AtomicInteger` incorrectly anyway. When you increment you should not be creating a new `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` doesn't make sense unless your program is multithreaded and you want to make sure the whole updation process happens atomically. So, weigh your options carefully before you write your code.

Comment: The `AtomicInteger` is here not the major problem. However, the way how the OP is using it is indeed overcomplicated and not well thought out. This can be done much simpler without the need to recreate a whole new instance on every single increment.

Comment: as the map is getting created inside the method, so you don't need to use any stuff related to multithreading. Because it will be assigned in the thread stack. simple integer will do.

Comment: @BalusC Exactly my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem at `A.put(key, one);` change it to `A.put(key, new AtomicInteger(1));` and this will work

also, there is really no sense in AtomicInteger, you can rewrite code as:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Long> A = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>(stuff.length);
for (String key: stuff)
    A.put(key, (A.containsKey(key)?A.get(key):0L)+1L);
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be accidentally reusing the same `AtomicInteger` value with different keys.   When you place an `AtomicInteger` into the map, it can be re-used when you call `get`.

Here's what's going on:

**Input: AAA**

It doesn't exist yet, so `one` is placed in the map.

**Input: A**

It doesn't exist yet, so `one` is placed in the map.  There are now two references to `one` in the map.

**Input: AA**

It doesn't exist yet, so `one` is placed in the map.  There are now three references to `one` in the map.

**Input: B**

It doesn't exist yet, so `one` is placed in the map.  There are now four references to `one` in the map.

**Input: A**

`A` already exists, so the value is retrieved.  Now `count` refers to the same object as `one`!  `count` is incremented, but a copy is made.  Now `AAA`, `AA`, and `B` are still mapped to the original `AtomicInteger`, but it's now wrong; it's `2`.  However, `A` refers to a second `AtomicInteger`, which is correct at `2`.

**Input: AAA**

`AAA` already exists, so the value is retrieved.  Now `count` refers to the same object as `one`, again!  `count` is incremented, but a copy is made.  Now, `AA` and `B` are still mapped to the original `AtomicInteger`, but it's now wrong; it's `3`.  However, `A` refers to the second `AtomicInteger` still, and it's still correct at `2`.  Additionally, `AAA` refers to a third `AtomicInteger`, but it's still wrong at `3`.

**Solution**

Change when you create new `AtomicInteger` objects, and just increment when you don't need new ones; they're mutable.

```
for (String key : stuff)  {
    AtomicInteger count = A.get(key);
    if (count == null)
        A.put(key, new AtomicInteger(1));
    else
        count.incrementAndGet();  // Modifies the object referred to in the map.
}
```

Comment: You can easily switch the accepted answer to the answer which helped the most in actually understanding and solving the concrete problem.